# I have installed cloudctl but when I try to login in command prompt getting 'cloudctl' not recognized error

Tags: ibm-cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eS6G.png)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What did you install and how did you install it? Are you sure the name of the command is not `ibmcloud`?

Comment: installed cloudctl and kubectl with below commands in cmd                                                                               
curl -kLo cloudctl-win-amd64-v3.2.0-634.exe https://10.101.6.242:8443/api/cli/cloudctl-win-amd64.exe                                                                       
 curl -kLo kubectl-win-amd64-v1.13.5.exe https://10.101.6.242:8443/api/cli/kubectl-win-amd64.exe 1.

Comment: As you haven't aliased or renamed the `cloudctl-win-amd64-v3.2.0-634.exe` you wrote to when running `curl`, `cloudctl-win-amd64-v3.2.0-634` would be the correct command name, not just `cloudctl`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple platform versions (Windows™, Linux®, or macOS )of the CloudCtl [Ref1], and install the appropriate CLI

you can list the files using curl

```
curl -kL https://--masterNodeIpAddress--:8443/api/cli 

"cloudctl-darwin-amd64"
"cloudctl-linux-amd64"
"cloudctl-linux-ppc64le"
"cloudctl-linux-s390x"
"cloudctl-win-amd64.exe"
```

- replace the --masterNodeIPAddress- for your cluster

---

##for linux x86

use the curl to download

```
curl -kLo /tmp/cloudctl-linux-amd64 https://--masterNodeIpAddress--:8443/api/cli/cloudctl-linux-amd64
```

Change permission to execute and copy to local path

```
chmod +x  /tmp/cloudctl-linux-amd64

cp /tmp/cloudctl-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/cloudctl
```

Login to the cluster

```
cloudctl login -a https://--masterNodeIpAddress--:8443
```

-- replace masteNodeIPaddress with  masternode IP address or haproxy, or load balancer used for the High availability master node

---

#### Customized Instructions to install clients from ICP console

You can also find the customized instructions for downloading and installing all the clients.
Log-in in to your IBM Cloud Private cluster management console from a   web browser.

- Connect to the URL https://masterORloadBalenacer:8443 and use the appropriate credentials.
- Menu ( left BurgerIcon) left navigation  -> CommandLine tools

Direct link https://masterORloadBalancerHostname:8443/console/tools/cli
[image]

Ref-1: **Installing the IBM® Cloud Private CLI**

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-private/3.2.0?topic=cloudctl-installing-cloud-private-cli